# Create a simple PDF file using perl

Tags: perl, pdf, cpan

I am parsing a text file in my perl script and wanted to dumb my hash to a pdf file. I dont really need to do formatting of data, just some plain text going to be there in the pdf file. Using a heavy cpan module would be an overkill for this simple task I guess.

What would be the best way to do this without using any externals modules.

I am on AIX 5.3 with perl 5.8

Answer (score 1):

Use the PDF::API2 package - see details [at the Oreilly site](http://oreilly.com/pub/h/2429)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately PDF is not a simple format. For one, it is binary, and the content is stored in a tree structure. However, if you have a tool like [`enscript`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.cmds%2Fdoc%2Faixcmds2%2Fenscript.htm) you can easily create a PS file from simple text input which you can then convert to a PDF.